# Operating System Process Management, Memory Management, Kernel

Tags: memory, process, operating-system, kernel, buffer

I am working in software firm where hardware independent coding is done on the Network Chipsets and fully Multigthreading coding implemented and various buffers(CRU Buffer, Linear Buffer) are handled and memory (stack memory) is optimally used. And IPC done via Message queues. And Multiple Locks, Semaphores are used for concurrency mechanisum. Now i will be assigned to new development project, where i have to understand and have to develop new features in next one month. I am feeling like middle of the Amazon Jungle :).

=> I am in beginning level in OS concepts. I feel like intermediate level in C language. So expecting, suggestion for "Materail/Book which could help me to improve/concrete my OS skills"

i saw OS Book by Abraham Silberschatz and Modern Operating Systems by Tanenbaum - 3rd Edition. Both are looking big and covers all corners of operating system. I thought to study that book steadily and slowly for future referencee.

==> Now i am looking for the Network materials/books which explaining the "Main concepts" in the detailed manner. For example i have seen virtual memory concepts in one online material where clearly virtual memory explained.

Example abour virtual memory from that material:

amesmol@aubergine:~/test> objdump -f a.out

a.out: file format elf32-i386 architecture: i386, flags 0x00000112: EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED start address 0x080482a0

explanation:

Notice the start address of the program is at 0x80482a0.Program thinks like where its starting address is actual physical address. But it is a virtual address space. Its original starting address at physical memory location 0x1000000.

As like this( correct point and example), could you people suggest good materials for the OS concepts ( Process Management, Memory Management, IPC)?
Can you also suggest the ways to improve/concrete this skills? (suggest either what kind of mini homework project i can do, etc..)

Thanks in advance

Comment: ya you are right. i am just asking the people who done this already and having list of reference with them. So its prevent me to reinvent the wheel :) . it seems you are learning embedded linux. so you could suggest me reference links and it helps me to save my time

Comment: There are many books. For one topic, one book is good and for another topic in another book is good. o'reilly books are good.

Comment: And you can't get good knowledge by books. You can only get by practising on system. So better to take training :)

Comment: Great resource which covers a lot of topics:
http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on projects you have to go over books you mentioned as soon as possible for theoretical explanations, concepts and terminologies. after that,even along with your reading, i suggest you to go to university websites to get hand on skills for small projects. some suggested links are as follows

http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~lie/Courses/ECE344/

http://web.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs140-winter13/pintos/pintos.html#SEC_Contents

http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~porter/courses/cse624/f13/project.html

(JOS implementation. very helping instructors if you send them specific queries)

http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev7.html

http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/intro.htm

(above two links are not university link but as a beginner I recommend this to start with )

apart from above, Lion's commentary on Unix code with line number reference must be in your reading to understand the implementation of small scale OS